# After Window.history.pushState() go back to prev URL

Tags: javascript

I have grid of products. Each product row in the grid can be expended to show the full product details (done with Ajax).

For SEO purposes when a row is expended am using :

```
window.history.pushState()
```

to change the URL.

For example:  URL such as:

```
http://mydomain.com/bouquets/cityName
```

will be changed to:

```
http://mydomain.com/bouquets/cityName/prodId
```

The problem is when another row expended the new URL will be:

```
http://mydomain.com/bouquets/cityName/prodId/prodId
```

The third row expended:

```
http://mydomain.com/bouquets/cityName/prodId/prodId/prodId/
```

and so on...

When a row expended after the first time, I need to do in JS something like:

```
<a href= "../URL" >
```

Comment: How are you calling `pushState`? If you're just appending to the URL, that would certainly cause that issue. Why not just save the original URL of the page instead of appending to the current URL?

Comment: How you suggest me to save the original URL? would you do it in a cookie?